# Making only some rows deletable in a UITableView [Swift 3.0 - Xcode 8]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, delete-row

I have an array `fruit = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Kiwi"]` that has Entity FOOD and is presented in an UItableView. Is there a way to make some content undeletable. For example, can I make `"Kiwi"` undeletable.

Something like, 
`let i = fruit.index(where: "Kiwi")
 let IArr = [0...fruit.count] 
 IArr = IArr.filter{$0 != i}` //deletes the index of Kiwi

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IArr) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    if editingStyle == .delete{
        let FRUIT = fruit[indexPath.row]
        context.delete(FRUIT)

        appDelegate.saveContext()
        do {
            fruit = try context.fetch(FOOD.fetchRequest())
        }
        catch
        {
            print("did not fetch")}
        }
        tableView.reloadData()}
```

However, this doesn't work because `indexPath` cannot take array types.
How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not really following you. You can simply disallow the delete action when the fruit is Kiwi: `let FRUIT = fruit[indexPath.row]; if editingStyle == .delete && FRUIT != "Kiwi" { /* delete */ }`

Comment: Thats an easy answer! thank you!

Comment: could you post anything in answers so I can mark yours as correct?

Comment: I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test that the row at the index path is not Kiwi:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IArr) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext {

    let FRUIT = fruit[indexPath.row]

    if editingStyle == .delete && FRUIT != "Kiwi" {
        /* delete */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont show editing part when slide left. You can use this.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

     let FRUIT = fruit[indexPath.row]

     if (FRUIT != "Kiwi") {
        return true
     }

     return false

    }
```